# Extracting key/value pairs form JSON array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this JSON(B) column in my postgres database. I thrown in this column all the data that I get from an API. Now i need to extract some key/value pairs from this array.e.g. for a JSON array like:

```
[{"myKey1": "school type", "myKey2": "primary"}, {"myKey1": "study coverage", "myKey2": "secondary"}]
```

i need to extract:

```
myKey1: school type   myKey2: primary

myKey1: study coverage  myKey22: secondary
```

Since i am new to JSON, to me it appears that i first need to break the array into objects (surrounded by curly brackets) and than there are some postgres functions for objects (given in the following link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) that i can use to extract the required key/value pairs.

My database table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "Education" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "json_text" JSONB NOT NULL,
);
```

I am using the following query to achieve this:

```
SELECT tmp_col->>'myKey1'
FROM ( 
  SELECT json_text->> 0 AS temp_col
  FROM education
) AS temp_table
```

I get the following error when i run this query.

[image: Error Message]

Any clues to what is missing?

Also is there any better ways to get the information in need. I am working in Java language to display the information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can then please try to process JSON in java. You can query the complete JSON from postgres and then by using [JSON API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) for Java you can then parse your JSON.